# How to add paragraphs and tables for Bokeh generated local html files

Tags: python, html, bokeh

I'm trying to use bokeh.plotting.output_file to generate my local reports. However, I find that I can only put charts in this file. Is there anyway that I can programmingly add description paragraphs or things like tables to my report html file?

Much appreciation!